# Solving the differential equation $y-x\frac{dy}{dx}-(\frac{dy}{dx})^2=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, singular-solution

Obtain the complete primitive and singular solutions of the differential equation: 
$$y-x\frac{dy}{dx}-(\frac{dy}{dx})^2=0$$

Could someone please explain to me how the equation can be solved?

Does it need to be translated to $$y''+xy'-y=0$$

and which type of method do you need to use to solve it?

Comment: Do you feel the difference between : $y''$ and $(y')^2$ ?

Comment: For example : $(x^2)'' = 2$ and $((x^2)' )^2 = 4x^2$

Comment: solve the equation for $$\frac{dy}{dx}$$

Comment: If its the first differential equation which is the original problem then I think it would be easier if you differentiate the equation which gives you $$-y''(2y'+x)=0$$ from here you get two differential equations to solve, which are pretty easy to do.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let us rewrite the equation as $$y-xy'-(y')^2=0$$
Differentiating both sides with respect to $x$, we get:
$$ y'-y'-xy''-2y'y''=0$$
or equivalently:
$$ xy''+2y'y''=y''(x+2y')=0$$
Thus $y''=0$ or $x+2y'=0$. If $y''=0$, then $y=c_1x+c_2$. If $x+2y'=0$, then $y'=\frac{-x}{2}$ and $y=-\frac{x^2}{4}+c_3$.

Therefore, the solution to your differential equation is $y=-\frac{x^2}{4}+c_3$ or $y=c_1x+c_2$.

Comment: You know even more by inserting the first derivative into the original equation. In the first case $y''=0$, one gets $y=cx+c^2$ with $c=y'$ and in the second $y=x·(-\frac x2)+(-\frac x2)^2=-\frac{x^2}4$. See Clairaut differential equation.

Comment: Please don't vandalize your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed, and thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to delete your answer, and can't because it's accepted, please raise a custom moderator flag explaining the situation.

Comment: Note : I've rolled back, but admittedly I have NOT checked that the solution doesn't have an issue. I'll do that as well!